# Difference between norm and distance.

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I was wondering the difference between norm and distance. My teacher told me that a norm always induce a distance, but that the reciprocal is not true. So, let $(E,\|\cdot \|)$ a normed space. I agree that we can give a structure of metric space by setting $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$. Now let $(E,d)$ a metric space. Why $\|x\|=d(x,0)$ would not be a norm over $E$ ?

Comment: To the norm you defined (i.e. $\|x\|:=d(x,0)$), can you show the homogeneity (i.e. $\|\lambda x\|=|\lambda|\|x\|$), and triangle inequality ? If yes, then indeed it would be a norm over $E$ (but I don't think that you will succeed :-))

Comment: What do you mean by "$0$"?

Comment: You don't have a zero element in an arbitrary metric space. You do not have operations in a metric space. The right question to ask is: does every metric in a *vector space* comes from a suitable norm? And the answer is no.

Comment: Simple example: let $E$ be a nontrivial vector space over the reals, and give it the discrete metric. There cannot be a norm such that $\|x-y\| = d(x,y)$. To see this, fix $y=0$ and observe any nonzero $x$ must satisfy $\|x\| = \|x-0\| = d(x,0) = 1$. Then any nonzero scalar multiple of $x$ must also satisfy $\|\alpha x\| = 1$, but the definition of a norm requires $\|\alpha x\| = |\alpha|\|x\|$.